# Can't access aws public ip via deploy or ping

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2

After I deploy my rails app via `passenger` and `nginx`, I want to test it.
So I type the public ip in browser and add `port`, it seems not work.

Beside, I can't ping the public ip as well.(Request timeout)

I've tried to add a new role in **Security Group** > **Inbond**. I choose `http` in type and `anywhere` in source option.

### Update

Here is my **Security Group setting**
[image]

Comment: i don't think this has anything to do with rails. if you can not even ping the public ip your aws settings are most likely wrong.

Comment: did you open that port in the firewall on the instance itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides security groups, to be able to access an instance over a public IP address, you need to make sure:

1. The instance is deployed in a VPC that has an [Internet Gateway](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Internet_Gateway.html) attached to it.
2. The subnet in which you deployed the instance has a [route](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Route_Tables.html) to the Internet Gateway.
3. The traffic into the subnet is not blocked by the [network ACL](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_ACLs.html) associated with the subnet.
4. The instance actually has a public IP automatically assigned to or [elastic IP](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html) associated with it (I'm assuming this is the case since you mentioned trying to ping it).
5. Failing that, it is time to look into the firewall on the instance, as mentioned in a comment above *(Note: most official AWS AMIs don't have firewall rules set since they typically utilize the aforementioned AWS VPC features for security)*.

This of course is assuming you're running in a VPC and not EC2-Classic (which hasn't been available to new AWS accounts for a while).

Comment: Yeah, I think I use VPC, because I use the free tier. I tried all ways, but still fails. I only have one machine, should I use the `elastic IP`?

Comment: I found out I set  Security Group wrongly. I should set it as 8080 port.